# At run time , How to get the path of the file and from which gem a particular object/class is loading in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

At run time , How to get the path of the file and from which gem a particular object/class is loading in ruby ?

To be specific, I am using a twitter Gem and getting an module "HTTP" while debugging in pry. I want to know from which Gem this module is coming. I tried HTTP.class and HTTP.class.name . It dint help much.

```
  [3] pry(#<Twitter::REST::Request>)> HTTP.class
   => Module
  [4] pry(#<Twitter::REST::Request>)> HTTP.class.name
  => "Module"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `HTTParty.method(:get).source_location`

Comment: its not working ...[6] pry(#<Twitter::REST::Request>)> HTTP
=> HTTP
[7] pry(#<Twitter::REST::Request>)> HTTP.method(:get).source_location
NameError: undefined method `get' for class `Module'
Did you mean?  gets
               gem
from (pry):9:in `method'
[8] pry(#<Twitter::REST::Request>)> HTTP.method(:gets).source_location
=> nil
[9] pry(#<Twitter::REST::Request>)>

Comment: I updated my answer. Basically, you need to know what method a class or a module implements and then call YourClass.method(:your_method).source_location. My example just illustrates how this works. I hope it makes sense to you now.